# how to display a component at a specific position in joomla template?

Tags: php, joomla

I have developed few custom components for joomla. Whenever I execute these components they appear at a specific position in template say the position name be 'showcase' what I wanna do now is

how to display the component at some other arbitrary position say 'showcase2'.

Help me out my project is stuck due to this???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Create the code you want to display as a module rather than a component. Components are designed to appear in the "main" portion of your page. If you need to, you can reference some of your component code from the module. I wouldn't recommend running the component in a wrapper in the module.

Note that **exactly one** component is run in each request to Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

To do this most people provide a companion module that can render the component in a module position.  Essentially this could just be a wrapper around the component with some simple parameters that have some fine tune control over the layout (e.g. max width, alternate style)